# How to save form record in client side while saving data with ajax POST?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery-ui, jquery

I have created one form.
On click Submit button record is saving in database with ajax POST.

Then again for viewing those records on web page I am clearing existing html and adding new records.

In form I am having select list and text-boxes and textarea.

**For example:**

**Following is my Form:**

On Click **Save FAQ**  button data from following form data is saving in database.

**Quetion No.** field is having unique no. for this I am generating number in backend.
Means when I do ajax POST **Question No** is blank but it is been assigned unique no. before putting in database.

[image: Form image]
**Requirements**:

Select list is present in that by default option value is **Default Mode(New)**.

**Question** field value need to get append in select list after clicking **Save FAQ**.
For this I am getting all records with Ajax GET and clear previous html and add new data but this is not feasible.

I need to optimize this.

For this I need to save this record in array, ex :

```
saveFaqRecordT = []
saveFaqRecordT.push({faq_no: getRec, faq_quest: rec.faq_quest, faq_answer: rec.faq_answer});
```

getRec is counter as we are no passing any value for Question No from client side.

**Or Please guide me with how to save record in client side also while saving doing Ajax POST, so that there is no need to do Ajax Get on each save?**

Answer (score 0):

Ajax Post -> Return appropriate response, let's say a JSON

On Success

```
{"status":"success","message":"added successfully"}
```

On Error

```
{"status":"error","message":"failed because of validation"}
```

Simply parse this JSON in the POST callback, to figure out where the saving was successful or not.

If the saving was successful, simply add the data to your `saveFaqRecordT` array.

```
$.ajax({
   method:POST,
   url:"http://someurl.com",
   data:$("#myform").serialize(),
   success:function(data){
      var json=eval(data);
      if(json.status=='success'){
           //append to array
      }   
   }
});
```

Above is just a sample un-tested code, to give you an idea on how it can be done.